# jenkins build - using ssh agent module - not able to run full set of commands on target machine

Tags: linux, jenkins, ssh

I'm trying to use the ssh agent module in jenkins to log in as me onto a remote machine... and run some lxc commands. 
I don't get any errors logging in but ... depending on the commands that I run, I'm either getting different results or permission denied errors.

This pastebin will show you the output I'm getting from Jenkins
http://pastebin.com/VxPHYzf9

In example 1, i'm trying to run an lxc command but it fails. 
In example 2, i run rc-status, expecting to see a list of running containers but I get something entirely different.

What I've tried so far:

1. When I manually ssh into the lxc host as user "johndoe" I am able to run both commands no problem. 
   I also have "watched" a log file on lxc that shows the ssh finger print who's logging in... and I can see that when jenkins does the build, it's logging in as "johndoe".
2. I've created a "jenkins" user / ssh key pair and also tried using that.  I get the same results.

The last test I tried which is not shown in the pastebin is just to run "ls -lah" on the tmp folder of the lxc host where I  know I have some bash files.
When i change the build to run these commands:

```
whoami
ssh -AtT root@10.111.11.11
ls -lah /tmp/*.sh
```

I get these results which again, are completely wrong:

```
+ whoami
jenkins
+ ssh -AtT root@10.111.11.11
********************************* ATTENTION **********************************
*            Unauthorized access prohibited.  Activity is logged.            *
******************************************************************************
 15:13:25 up 23 days, 19:33,  0 users,  load average: 0.11, 0.07, 0.11
+ ls -lah /tmp/hudson3065491328414451721.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins 52 Jun 10 11:13 /tmp/hudson3065491328414451721.sh
[ssh-agent] Stopped.
Finished: SUCCESS
```

I have at least 3 sh files ... and I don't know what the hudson*.sh file is.

Ultimately, I need Jenkins to be able to log into the lxc host and run a bunch of commands as a part of my build.

Any help would be appreciated.

I'm also going to try to get the build to ssh into a different machine to see if I get different results.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

It looks like my mistake was putting all my shell commands for the remote server on separate lines. 
So for example,in the build "Execute Shell" text box i had something like this:

```
   ssh -A root@10.1.1.1
   whoami
   ls -lah /tmp/*.sh
```

What it was doing was logging into the remote server, and then running the other two commands on my LOCAL jenkins server.

So I changed the shell commands to look like this:

```
   ssh- A root@10.1.1.1 'ls -lah'
```

and now it's working.